# What are the ways of making DNS query in Chrome/Opera's web extensions API?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently developing browser extension, which will block malicious websites which try to access internal network via browser (using it as proxy basically). Obviously I'm using WebExtensions API. I'm intercepting the requests via WebRequest API, where I receive host names for both - request origin and request target. In this case I would need to translate these hostnames to IP adresses to find out whether server with public IP range is trying to make requests to local IP ranges. Mozilla Firefox's WebExtensions API contains API called dns, which I'm currently using like that:

```
browser.dns.resolve(hostname)
```

I did not find similar APIs for either Chrome nor Opera and that's where problem appears. I'd like to make my extension compatible at least for Chrome, Firefox, Opera.. but how can I, if the API is simply missing? I found text stating, that dns API in Chrome was deprecated, so my question is - **is there any way how to make DNS query in Chrome and Opera browser extensions?**

Comment: There is no API for this in Chrome extensions so you'll have to use a public external service or write a utility and run it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Public external service -  what would you recommend?

Comment: I haven't used any so no idea.

Comment: If I can't query the DNS server myself, isn't possible to somehow intercept the DNS queries and read corresponding IP address from there? I mean.. browser needs to make DNS query anyways, right?

Comment: There is no "somehow" if Chrome doesn't expose the API.

Comment: That's sad. I'd say it's common thing to be able to translate hostnames to IPs. Anyways, thanks for your answers.